# How do I make an entity move in a direction?

Tags: java, movement, rotation, trigonometry

I have an `Entity` instance which is updated every game tick. Let's just assume that entity moves forward constantly. I'd like to be able to give the entity's angle to a function that makes it move in that direction:

`moveForward(90);` should make them move to the right. If I declared my rotation as a global `int`, then doing

```
moveForward(rotation);
rotation++;
```

would make it trace a small circle with its movement.

How can I do this? I assume this involves vector math; I don't know any, so a brief explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well in the simplest sense you have something like this.

```
   y  |\
      | \
   m  |  \         s
   o  |   \        p
   v  |(a) \       e
(y)e  |angle\      e
   m  |      \     d
   e  |       \
   n  |        \
   t  |         \
      |__________\
      x movement
        (x)
```

The speed is however fast the enemy is, and you can determine how much they should move in the x direction and how much they move in the y direction by taking the sin or cos of the angle and multiplying by speed. Because...

```
 sin(a) = x / speed
```

So:

```
 x = speed * sin(a)
```

And:

```
cos(a) = y / speed
```

So:

```
y = speed * cos(a)
```

In your example `moveForward(90)` would yield `speed * sin(90)` or `speed * 1` in the x direction and `speed * cos(90)` or `0` in the y direction (It should move to the right as you specified).  That should get you started in the basic sense.

Making it general:

```
moveForward(float angle)
{
    x += speed * sin(angle);
    y += speed * cos(angle);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thats a lot simpler than i imagined, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to switch y's and x's. sin(alpha) = b/c.

Comment: @Bane it matches the drawing I made SOH-CAH-TOA, sin is opposite over hypotenuse which in the drawing is x / speed.  If the angle were on the other side of the triangle it would be reversed (and if that is more practical for the purpose of game design I could change it, but I feel its all arbitrary).

Comment: I'm on my mobile phone so it was pretty hard to interpret that. I just skimmed over the formulas...

Comment: That's a really nice triangle you got there. +1

Comment: this answer and the question are so underrated

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is wrong as of now, to correctly move along a plane based on a rotation you do the following:

```
posX += Math.cos(rotation) *  forwardSpeed + Math.sin(rotation) * strafeSpeed;
posY -= -Math.cos(rotation) * strafeSpeed + Math.sin(rotation) * forwardSpeed;
```

However I'd recommend making a variable for cos/sin that you update only when the rotation changes so you aren't calculating it 4 times a tick.

The strafeSpeed would be moving from side to side, the forwardSpeed for moving forward along your rotation.

edit: tesselode does the same thing except he doesnt have side to side movement.

Answer (score 2):

You said update ticks, so I'm assuming you don't have a variable frame rate. If so:

x += speed * math.cos(angle)

y += speed * math.sin(angle)

If you're using variable frame rate, you need to multiply by delta time as well.